# Dovecot dsync replication setup

Tags: dovecot, replication

I'm using dovecot with master/master replication using dsync, and I did the setup as described on

https://wiki.dovecot.org/Replication

What is total unclear to me, and I could not figure it out until now.

Do I have to setup the replication in both directions?

```
    serverA dsyncs to serverB
```

and

```
    serverB dsyncs to serverA
```

Currenty I did the setup in both directions, but I have the strange feeling that sth. Is wrong as my e-Mail clients are downloading thousands of emails over and over again when I connect.